# How to call UIBezier outline in Swift Playground?

Tags: swift, uibezierpath

EDIT: Sorry, I wasn't clear originally. I want to get the "outline" path of a line or shape. I'm specifically trying to understand how to use:

```
context.replacePathWithStrokedPath()
```

and / or:

```
CGPathRef CGPathCreateCopyByStrokingPath(CGPathRef path, const CGAffineTransform *transform, CGFloat lineWidth, CGLineCap lineCap, CGLineJoin lineJoin, CGFloat miterLimit);
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/1411128-cgpathcreatecopybystrokingpath?language=objc

I'm not looking for workarounds, thanks.

=====

I'm really trying to wrap my head around drawing a line with an outline around it. i'm using UIBezier, but running into brick walls. So far, I've got this:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

let screenWidth = 375.0 // points
let screenHeight = 467.0 // points

let centerX = screenWidth / 2.0
let centerY = screenHeight / 2.0

let screenCenterCoordinate = CGPoint(x: centerX, y: centerY)

class LineDrawingView: UIView {
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    let path = UIBezierPath()
    path.lineWidth = 5
    path.lineCapStyle = .round

    //Move to Drawing Point
    path.move(to: CGPoint(x:20, y:120))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:200, y:120))

    path.stroke()

    let dot = UIBezierPath()
    dot.lineWidth = 1
    dot.lineCapStyle = .round

    dot.move(to: CGPoint(x:200, y:120))
    dot.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x:200, y:120), radius: 5, startAngle: CGFloat(0.0), endAngle: CGFloat(8.0), clockwise: true)

    UIColor.orange.setStroke()
    UIColor.orange.setFill()
    path.stroke()
    dot.fill()

    let myStrokedPath = UIBezierPath.copy(path)

    myStrokedPath().stroke()

  }

}


let tView = LineDrawingView(frame: CGRect(x: 0,y: 0, width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight))
tView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = tView
```

So, where am I going wrong in this? I cannot seem to figure out where to use CGPathCreateCopyByStrokingPath...or how...

EDIT 2:

Ok, now I've got this. Closer, but how do I fill the path again?

```
    let c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!

    c.setLineWidth(15.0)

    let clipPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x:centerX,y:centerY), radius: 90.0, startAngle: -0.5 * .pi, endAngle: 1.0 * .pi, clockwise: true).cgPath

    c.addPath(clipPath)
    c.saveGState()
    c.replacePathWithStrokedPath()

    c.setLineWidth(0.2)
    c.setStrokeColor(UIColor.black.cgColor)
    c.strokePath()
```

Answer (score 0):

The class was modified slightly to produce this graphic:

[image: OrangeLineWithOutline]

The path was not copied in the modified code. Instead the existing path was used to draw, then modified and reused. The dot did not have a stroke so that was added. Since only closed paths can be filled, I drew a thinner path on top of a thicker path by changing the line width.

This is the modified code:

```
class LineDrawingView: UIView {
  override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    let path = UIBezierPath()
    path.lineWidth = 7
    path.lineCapStyle = .round

    //Move to Drawing Point
    path.move(to: CGPoint(x:20, y:120))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:200, y:120))

    path.stroke()

    let dot = UIBezierPath()
    dot.lineWidth = 1
    dot.lineCapStyle = .round

    dot.move(to: CGPoint(x:200, y:120))
    dot.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x:200, y:120), radius: 5, startAngle: CGFloat(0.0), endAngle: CGFloat(8.0), clockwise: true)

    dot.stroke()

    UIColor.orange.setStroke()
    UIColor.orange.setFill()
    path.lineWidth = 5
    path.stroke()
    dot.fill()

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I've found the (an) answer. I used CAShapeLayer:

```
let c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!

    c.setLineCap(.round)
    c.setLineWidth(15.0)

    c.addArc(center: CGPoint(x:centerX,y:centerY), radius: 90.0, startAngle: -0.5 * .pi, endAngle: (-0.5 * .pi) + (3 / 2 * .pi ), clockwise: false)

    c.replacePathWithStrokedPath()

    let shape = CAShapeLayer()
    shape.path = c.path
    shape.fillColor = UIColor.yellow.cgColor
    shape.strokeColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
    shape.lineWidth = 1

    myView.layer.addSublayer(shape)
```

It works well enough, but not on overlapping layers. I need to learn how to connect contours or something.